# MomentJS possible bug with the add() function

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'd like to add several months in an array but I cannot get the add() function of MomentJS to work properly. Here's how it goes :

```
    function getMonths(begin, end){
        var cursor = moment(begin);
        var momentEnd = moment(end);
        var arrayMonths = [];
        while(cursor.month() != momentEnd.month() || cursor.year() != momentEnd.year()){        
            cursor.add(1, 'month'); // Actually adds one month to the cursor
            console.log(cursor.toDate()); // Because this display the cursor with an added month
            arrayMonths.push(cursor.toDate()); // However the cursor being pushed doesn't have this added month
            console.log(arrayMonths); // verified here
        }       
        return arrayMonths;
    }
```

The console log shows that the cursor has actually been incremented (as add() is a mutator) however its proper value isn't added to the array.

I cannot figure out if this is an issue in my code or if it is inherent to MomentJS. Does anybody have any clue ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for `toDate` says:

> To get the native Date object that Moment.js wraps, use moment#toDate.
>
> This will return the Date that the moment uses, so any changes to that Date will cause the moment to change. If you want a Date that is a copy, use moment#clone before you use moment#toDate.

IE you're getting *the same* underlying `Date` object every time you call `toDate` - ie each call to `add` is also modifying it, and every member of the array is actually the same object.

If you do as the documentation says, and use `clone`, your code works:

```
arrayMonths.push(cursor.clone().toDate());
```

Here's a demo:

```js
function getMonths(begin, end){
  var cursor = moment(begin);
  var momentEnd = moment(end);
  var arrayMonths = [];
  while(cursor.month() != momentEnd.month() || cursor.year() != momentEnd.year()){        
    cursor.add(1, 'month'); // Actually adds one month to the cursor
    console.log(cursor.toDate()); // Because this display the cursor with an added month
    
    //clone the object before pushing, to ensure it's not further modified
    arrayMonths.push(cursor.clone().toDate()); 
    
    console.log(arrayMonths); // verified here
  }       
  return arrayMonths;
}
    
    
getMonths(moment('2016/01/01', 'YYYY/MM/DD'), moment('2017/01/01', 'YYYY/MM/DD'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution worked ! However it seems rather counter-intuitive that displaying the result of toDate() in the log shows a different result.

Answer (score -1):

Not entirely sure what's happening here as your code looks OK.

I would however try using and temporary variable to double check what's happening.

```
function getMonths(begin, end){
    var cursor = moment(begin);
    var momentEnd = moment(end);
    var arrayMonths = [];
    while(cursor.month() != momentEnd.month() || cursor.year() != momentEnd.year()){        
        cursor.add(1, 'month');
        var cursorDate = cursor.toDate();
        console.log(cursorDate); // temporary variable - no chance it gets mutated etc...
        arrayMonths.push(cursorDate); 
        console.log(arrayMonths);
    }       
    return arrayMonths;
}
```